# store.query response expected to be an array but it was a single record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am making an API call to get the conference rooms that match the profided filters.  The response is returning an array, however Ember is giving me the error:

*Error while processing route: rooms Assertion Failed: The response to store.query is expected to be an array but it was a single record. Please wrap your response in an array or use `store.queryRecord` to query for a single record.*

I am using RESTAdapter.

What am I doing wrong?

route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return this.store.query('room', { filter: { option1: 'x', option2: 'y' } }).then(function(rooms) {
        return rooms;
    });
  }
});
```

Returned by server:

```
{"rooms":[
    {"id":"1","size":"600","title":"Centennial Room","description":""},
    {"id":"3","size":"1500","title":"Grand Auditorium","description":""}
]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your serializer?

Comment: I haven't created one.

Comment: It's told that `RESTSerializer` is the default. To ensure please create `application.js` in your serializer folder by `ember g serializer application` command and extend from `RESTSerializer` with importing `import RESTSerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/rest';`

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with pluralization.  I'm using pods, and the folder's name (and therefore the model's name, and the URL) was `rooms`.  I changed it to `room` and the error went away.

There was also an ember warning, but I ignored it, paying attention to the error instead.  Fixing the warning would have fixed the error.